# Current font used in a Text object in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to get/obtain the current font used in a Text object in SwiftUI?  ex. `Text("abc").font()` does not work.

Comment: Why do you need that information?

Comment: I want to increase the font size

Answer (score 7):

The current font is accessible from the environment:

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
    @Environment(\.font) var font

    var body: some View {
        Text("Italic version of the hierarchy's font")
            .font((font ?? .body).italic())
    }
}
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues for the full list of available keys, they can come in handy.

Answer (score -1):

You can use systemFont.

```
 Text("ddd").font(Font.system(size: 50))
```

So you don't need to know exact name of the font.